# How can I use appcompat-v7:19.1 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 1.3 generate a build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

but I want use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1`, when I type this, it tips Failed to resolve: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1`

How can I use appcompat-v7 with lower version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency to *{project}/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
}
```

Click the Sync Project with `Gradle Files` button.
I hope it helps you.

For more info please visit:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
}
```

Also ensure that you have those libraries installed.